# Angular in memory db

Tags: angular, in-memory-database, angular-in-memory-web-api

I'm currently using in-memory-db package (angular-in-memory-web-api) and I'm not be able to make requests like:

api/products/authors --> **doesn't work**

I should stop at products path, Indeed:

api/products --> **works fine**

Could you give me any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Both path is exactly the same... `api/products/authors` so does it work or does it not...?

Comment: sorry I meant api/products works fine

Comment: @penleychan any tips?